# After the training of the train set in Python, the value of accurancy, recall and f1-score is 0

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network, metrics, training-data, flair

I am using the Flair library in python for a Fake News Detection problem, using an RNN-based algorithm. The code does not give errors, but the training phase is excessively slow and also at the end of that phase the metrics used for evaluation (accuracy, recall, f1-score) take value 0.

The function used for the training phase is ModelTrainer.train(//various parameters).
The dataset has undergone pre-processing, so I don't think there are any errors in the data, having also removed the empty sentences with Flair's filter_empty_sentence() function.

Comment: What happens when you remove most of the training data and only train on a very small subset (~5 examples)?

Comment: I try to use a training set of 10 samples, but there is the same problem explained above